# Manipulating time series data in R

Tags: r, time-series

What would be a good way to manipulate the following type of times series data in `R`:

```
username;variable;2012-01-01;2012-01-15;2012-02-01;2012-03-01;2012-04-01;2012-05-01;2012-07-02 
user1;var1;5;5;5;5;6;6;6
user1;var2;0;0;1;0;0;1;1
user1;var3;9;9;9;9;9;9;9
user2;var1;4;4;4;4;4;6;6
user2;var2;0;0;1;1;1;1;1
user2;var3;4;4;4;9;9;9;9
```

The data contains a set of time series for each monitored user. My goal is to have the data in such a format that I can easily make queries upon this data set for "deltas". That is, from a certain point in time I can look back and compute how long ago a certain variable changed and also get the original value and the new value from this query.

A function that would simply take a date and variable name as an argument would be perfect, e.g, `fun(2012-07-02, var1)`, `fun(2012-02-17, var1)` or `fun(2014-09-02, var1)` would return four columns: `username,original_value;new_value;days_since_change`.

Are there `R` packages or pieces of code that would be able to do something similar?

Comment: How would `date1-7` map to `2012-07-02`?

Comment: Poor example, date1-7 are actually dates in format yyyy-mm-dd. I'll correct it.

Comment: Not sure about your answer, but I think package data.table might be very helpful.

Comment: So in your example `fun`, --I edited to make the last date July -- since July2012 is out of range, would your output be `user1,5,5,4` and `user2,4,6,3` ?

Comment: The function would return the result for all users. For user1 `user1;5;6;92` and for user2 `user2;4;6;62`. that is, what the change in value was, and how many days has passed sine this change. So now date specified in the function is out of range.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to transform your table in a easy to work with format. the trick to to use the `reshape2` package and `melt` your data.

```
my.table <-read.table(text="username;variable;2012-01-01;2012-01-15;2012-02-01;2012-03-01;2012-04-01;2012-05-01;2012-07-02
user1;var1;5;5;5;5;6;6;6
user1;var2;0;0;1;0;0;1;1
user1;var3;9;9;9;9;9;9;9
user2;var1;4;4;4;4;4;6;6
user2;var2;0;0;1;1;1;1;1
user2;var3;4;4;4;9;9;9;9",sep=";", header=TRUE)

library(reshape2)
res <-melt(my.table,id.vars=c("username","variable") )    #melt on the first two columns
colnames(res)[3] <-"Date"
res$Date <-as.Date(res$Date,format="X%Y.%m.%d")           #transform into date format

out <-res[res$username=="user1" & res$variable=="var1",]  #request user1 and var1
out

   username variable       Date value
1     user1     var1 2012-01-01     5
7     user1     var1 2012-01-15     5
13    user1     var1 2012-02-01     5
19    user1     var1 2012-03-01     5
25    user1     var1 2012-04-01     6
31    user1     var1 2012-05-01     6
37    user1     var1 2012-07-02     6
```

I do not understand what you want when you say `original_value;new_value;days_since_change` but with data extracted in such a way, I'm sure you can figure it out.

Comment: Thank you. I added a comment and edited my original post where I explain my fun() output a bit more closely. Melt could be a good solution, but I'm a bit wary about the size of the table: there are millions of users, some hundreds of dates and around ten variables.